# Is it possible to, if i have a nav bar in my header element to, drop it down when resizing?

Tags: html, css

i'm looking to get my nav bar thats in my header

```
<header>
  <nav style="width: 960px; margin: auto; padding-top: 20px;">
    <div id="myName">
      Grayson McMurry
    </div>
    <div id="myNav">
      <!--id tag used because the content is unique-->
      <a href="index.html">About</a> |
      <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a> |
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <hr style="margin: 0px;" />
  <!--line in html styled-->
</header>
```

heres the css that goes along with it

```
#myNav {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

i want to be able to drop it down when resizing the web page to make it mobile responsive. is it possible to do it either in the header element to make it taller or to drop it down completely out of the header element itself?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "drop it down"? Did you want to stack the links vertically or move the nav itself down the page or what were you thinking?

Answer (score 0):

A few adjustments.

1. Remove the set width on your nav element.
2. Remove `float` from your nav links and let flexbox do all the work..

I've removed your inline styles and add a wrapping id of `navWrapper` on your `nav` element.

Result:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <nav id="navWrapper">
    <div id="myName">
      Grayson McMurry
    </div>
    <div id="myNav">
      <!--id tag used because the content is unique-->
      <a href="index.html">About</a> |
      <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a> |
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <hr style="margin: 0px;" />
  <!--line in html styled-->
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#navWrapper {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#myNav {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #d3d3d3;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```